# Angular Unit-testing with service layer HttpTestingController Error: Expected no open requests found GET

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, web-services, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test my service layer within Angular, but when I try to mock the http requests for get, post and put, I get an Error saying it couldn't find an open request but found 1

I already tried to search multiple posts with this issue but none seem to have come to my rescue, but I seem to end up to no avail

```
it('should be able load company data', inject([HttpClient], (http: HttpClient) => {
const companyList: CompanyVerificationResponseDto = {
  companyName: 'testcompany',
  kvkNumber: 12345678,
  companyPhone: '0612341234',
  email: 'testtest@email.com',
  accountStatus: 0,
  contactPhone: '0631313131'
};

managementService.loadData();

const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const param = new HttpParams().set('token', '1234-1234-1234').append('email', 'testtest@email.com');
const options = {params: param, headers: headers};


http.get('http://localhost:8080/adminpage', options).subscribe(() => {

});

const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:8080/adminpage?token=1234-1234-1234&email=testtest@email.com');
expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

req.flush(companyList);
}));

afterEach(() => {
   httpMock.verify();
});
```

and my actual service method goes like this:

```
public loadData() {
this.restfulService.url = this.restfulService.getBaseUrl() + '/adminpage';
const param = new HttpParams().set('token', this.restfulService.getLocalStorageToken().token);
const options = {params: param, headers: this.headers};

return this.httpClient.get<CompanyVerificationResponseDto[]>(this.restfulService.url, options).subscribe(data => {
    this.companyList = data;
    this.onSuccesfulReceivedData(data);
  },
  error => this.restfulService.handleError(error));
}
```

But I get this error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ManagementService should be able to accept a company based on email FAILED
    Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: GET http://localhost:8080/adminpage in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js (line 32166)
    verify@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:32166:97
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:3356:24
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:6843:31
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:156148:45
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:6842:40
    run@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:6593:49
    runInTestZone@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:156369:37
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:156384:33
    invoke@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:6843:31
    run@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:6593:49
    http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:7327:37
    invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:6876:36
    runTask@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:6643:57
    drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:7050:42
```

I expect it to pass saying the request method is a get request, but the actual result is an error.

Comment: This is probably because Angular checks the URL *with query parameters* and the order may not be what you expect, see e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19974#issuecomment-342827258 for a workaround.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, this now seems to work. Appreciated!